# gnuplot: animated heatmap is not created properly

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap, gif

My data is formatted this way (x, y, t, e):

[image]

I can't get an animated heatmap (in the gif format out of it). Here is my code:

```
set view map scale 1
set size square
set xlabel("x (m)")
set ylabel("y (m)")
set zlabel("V/m")
set title "E_z evolution"
set cblabel "E (V/m)"

set xrange [0:200]
set yrange [0:200]
set zrange [0:200]

set pm3d implicit at s 
set pm3d corners2color max 

set term gif animate delay 100 

set output "electric_field_evo.gif"
DATA = "result.dat"
stats DATA using 4

do for [i=1:int(STATS_blocks)]{
    splot DATA index (i-1) every 1::1::1 using (t=$3):(NaN):(NaN) notitle, \
          DATA index (i-1) using 1:2:4 with pm3d title sprintf("time = %g",t)
}

# do for [i=1:int(STATS_blocks)]{
#     splot DATA index (i-1) using 1:2:(t=$3,$4) with pm3d title sprintf("time = %g",t)
# 
# }
```

And the result (sample from the gif for t = 190, but the whole gif looks like that: empty heatmap), notice heatmap is empty, and legend limit on the right keep changing frame after frame (they should be set to overall min/max):

[image]

Result from the `stats` call:

[image]

EDIT: ADD SAMPLE DATA

```
       1             1            10    0.0000000E+00
       1             2            10    0.0000000E+00
       1             3            10    0.0000000E+00
       1             4            10    0.0000000E+00
       1             5            10    0.0000000E+00
       1             6            10    0.0000000E+00
       1             7            10    0.0000000E+00
       1             8            10    0.0000000E+00
       1             9            10    0.0000000E+00
       1            10            10    0.0000000E+00
       2             1            10    0.0000000E+00
       2             2            10   -2.4976539E-06
       2             3            10   -5.3808012E-04
       2             4            10   -2.6733600E-02
       2             5            10     1.610434    
       2             6            10   -2.6733600E-02
       2             7            10   -5.3808012E-04
       2             8            10   -2.4976580E-06
       2             9            10   -4.8060720E-09
       2            10            10    0.0000000E+00
       3             1            10    0.0000000E+00
       3             2            10   -4.0286686E-06
       3             3            10   -8.8682520E-04
       3             4            10   -6.8456993E-02
       3             5            10    0.8074945    
       3             6            10   -6.8456993E-02
       3             7            10   -8.8682520E-04
       3             8            10   -4.0286805E-06
       3             9            10   -9.2283745E-09
       3            10            10    0.0000000E+00
       4             1            10    0.0000000E+00
       4             2            10   -5.1066436E-06
       4             3            10   -1.0590287E-03
       4             4            10   -8.2134798E-02
       4             5            10    2.1518860E-02
       4             6            10   -8.2134798E-02
       4             7            10   -1.0590287E-03
       4             8            10   -5.1066618E-06
       4             9            10   -1.2548365E-08
       4            10            10    0.0000000E+00
       5             1            10    0.0000000E+00
       5             2            10   -5.3812091E-06
       5             3            10   -1.0855671E-03
       5             4            10   -8.8276833E-02
       5             5            10   -0.3647908    
       5             6            10   -8.8276833E-02
       5             7            10   -1.0855671E-03
       5             8            10   -5.3812300E-06
       5             9            10   -1.4017410E-08
       5            10            10    0.0000000E+00
       6             1            10    0.0000000E+00
       6             2            10   -5.1066436E-06
       6             3            10   -1.0618623E-03
       6             4            10   -8.5113689E-02
       6             5            10   -0.6305632    
       6             6            10   -8.5113689E-02
       6             7            10   -1.0618623E-03
       6             8            10   -5.1066618E-06
       6             9            10   -1.2548365E-08
       6            10            10    0.0000000E+00
       7             1            10    0.0000000E+00
       7             2            10   -4.0534715E-06
       7             3            10   -9.2593604E-04
       7             4            10   -8.5873455E-02
       7             5            10    -1.141478    
       7             6            10   -8.5873455E-02
       7             7            10   -9.2593604E-04
       7             8            10   -4.0534824E-06
       7             9            10   -9.2283745E-09
       7            10            10    0.0000000E+00
       8             1            10    0.0000000E+00
       8             2            10   -2.7910814E-06
       8             3            10   -7.3620438E-04
       8             4            10   -7.2833136E-02
       8             5            10   -0.6117640    
       8             6            10   -7.2833136E-02
       8             7            10   -7.3620438E-04
       8             8            10   -2.7910855E-06
       8             9            10   -4.9456297E-09
       8            10            10    0.0000000E+00
       9             1            10    0.0000000E+00
       9             2            10   -1.2563974E-06
       9             3            10   -4.6025845E-04
       9             4            10   -5.4116480E-02
       9             5            10    0.2660810    
       9             6            10   -5.4116480E-02
       9             7            10   -4.6025845E-04
       9             8            10   -1.2563978E-06
       9             9            10   -1.3758922E-09
       9            10            10    0.0000000E+00
      10             1            10    0.0000000E+00
      10             2            10    0.0000000E+00
      10             3            10    0.0000000E+00
      10             4            10    0.0000000E+00
      10             5            10    0.0000000E+00
      10             6            10    0.0000000E+00
      10             7            10    0.0000000E+00
      10             8            10    0.0000000E+00
      10             9            10    0.0000000E+00
      10            10            10    0.0000000E+00


       1             1            20    0.0000000E+00
       1             2            20    0.0000000E+00
       1             3            20    0.0000000E+00
       1             4            20    0.0000000E+00
       1             5            20    0.0000000E+00
       1             6            20    0.0000000E+00
       1             7            20    0.0000000E+00
       1             8            20    0.0000000E+00
       1             9            20    0.0000000E+00
       1            10            20    0.0000000E+00
       2             1            20    0.0000000E+00
       2             2            20   -6.1337640E-05
       2             3            20   -1.4902533E-03
       2             4            20    3.2542488E-03
       2             5            20    0.3296941    
       2             6            20    3.2542488E-03
       2             7            20   -1.4902533E-03
       2             8            20   -6.1346022E-05
       2             9            20   -9.6680935E-07
       2            10            20    0.0000000E+00
       3             1            20    0.0000000E+00
       3             2            20   -1.1673706E-04
       3             3            20   -2.5404668E-03
       3             4            20    4.2203847E-02
       3             5            20     1.418503    
       3             6            20    4.2203847E-02
       3             7            20   -2.5404671E-03
       3             8            20   -1.1675285E-04
       3             9            20   -1.8424856E-06
       3            10            20    0.0000000E+00
       4             1            20    0.0000000E+00
       4             2            20   -1.5823430E-04
       4             3            20   -2.6485780E-03
       4             4            20    9.9604763E-02
       4             5            20     1.320845    
       4             6            20    9.9604763E-02
       4             7            20   -2.6485780E-03
       4             8            20   -1.5825577E-04
       4             9            20   -2.5378417E-06
       4            10            20    0.0000000E+00
       5             1            20    0.0000000E+00
       5             2            20   -1.7999914E-04
       5             3            20   -2.5499274E-03
       5             4            20    0.1251577    
       5             5            20     2.412011    
       5             6            20    0.1251577    
       5             7            20   -2.5499277E-03
       5             8            20   -1.8002378E-04
       5             9            20   -2.9330913E-06
       5            10            20    0.0000000E+00
       6             1            20    0.0000000E+00
       6             2            20   -1.7958798E-04
       6             3            20   -2.3236359E-03
       6             4            20    0.1080537    
       6             5            20    0.6282932    
       6             6            20    0.1080537    
       6             7            20   -2.3236363E-03
       6             8            20   -1.7961276E-04
       6             9            20   -2.9684843E-06
       6            10            20    0.0000000E+00
       7             1            20    0.0000000E+00
       7             2            20   -1.6216180E-04
       7             3            20   -2.0380928E-03
       7             4            20    0.1280525    
       7             5            20   -0.2143435    
       7             6            20    0.1280525    
       7             7            20   -2.0380928E-03
       7             8            20   -1.6218355E-04
       7             9            20   -2.6321391E-06
       7            10            20    0.0000000E+00
       8             1            20    0.0000000E+00
       8             2            20   -1.2343809E-04
       8             3            20   -1.6553155E-03
       8             4            20    0.1108039    
       8             5            20   -0.6842759    
       8             6            20    0.1108039    
       8             7            20   -1.6553155E-03
       8             8            20   -1.2345419E-04
       8             9            20   -1.9603046E-06
       8            10            20    0.0000000E+00
       9             1            20    0.0000000E+00
       9             2            20   -6.7093235E-05
       9             3            20   -1.1316845E-03
       9             4            20    6.1340898E-02
       9             5            20    0.1410470    
       9             6            20    6.1340898E-02
       9             7            20   -1.1316845E-03
       9             8            20   -6.7101741E-05
       9             9            20   -1.0376655E-06
       9            10            20    0.0000000E+00
      10             1            20    0.0000000E+00
      10             2            20    0.0000000E+00
      10             3            20    0.0000000E+00
      10             4            20    0.0000000E+00
      10             5            20    0.0000000E+00
      10             6            20    0.0000000E+00
      10             7            20    0.0000000E+00
      10             8            20    0.0000000E+00
      10             9            20    0.0000000E+00
      10            10            20    0.0000000E+00
```

Comment: Without having your data it's difficult to say what's going wrong at `t=190`. Which block number does this correspond to, maybe the last one? Can you maybe provide the data (well, probably too large to post here)? Concerning the colorbar, you have to fix the range, e.g. `set cbrange [0:50]`.

Comment: it's not only t=190. It's the whole thing. t=190 is just an example of what I am getting for each and every data block.

Comment: Without having the data I cannot test and see whether it is because of the script or because of the data. That's why a minimal, reproducible example is so important! https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Done. Added sample data. I had to significantly reduce the simulation size.

Comment: Thank you for adding the data. And here we go: for `pm3d` gnuplot expects an empty line after each "scan"line. `Warning: Single isoline (scan) is not enough for a pm3d plot.
           Hint: Missing blank lines in the data file? See 'help pm3d' and FAQ.` That means: after each line with 10 in the second column there should be an empty line. Either you change your data accordingly or you need a workaround.

Comment: OK I think I get it. If you want to add a reply, I'll gladly accept your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, gnuplot expects a certain data structure for `splot ... with pm3d`.
See the following minimized example. If you can change your data in that way it would be the easiest. Otherwise, if you cannot or don't want to change your original datafiles you can think about some workaround and [insert the empty line with gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56857432/7295599).

Required data format:

```
  1   1   1.1   # 1st block start, index=0
  1   2   1.2
  1   3   1.3   # one blank line follows

  2   1   1.4
  2   2   1.5
  2   3   1.6   # one blank line follows

  3   1   1.7
  3   2   1.8
  3   3   1.9   # 1st block end, followed by two blank lines


  1   1   2.1   # 2nd block start, index=1
  1   2   2.2
  1   3   2.3   # one blank line follows

  2   1   2.4
  2   2   2.5
  2   3   2.6   # one blank line follows

  3   1   2.7
  3   2   2.8
  3   3   2.9
```

Comment: I edited the format of my data and it worked. Last bit of question: any idea why the "time = xxx" is located within the plot? I would like it to be next to the title at the top.

Comment: @CTZStef add something like `set key out` or a defined position. Check `help key`. Default position for the legend is inside top right. Which version of gnuplot are you running? Maybe you can also simplify the creation of the title, i.e. without plotting `NaN`.